# Disable direct access php file but not include

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, include

I want to disable a vulnerability in PHPFox(phpfoxsite.com/static/ajax.php).  Here is an example of the bug - http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2014/Apr/23

My tests :

In .htaccess

```
Deny from all
```

In PHP file ( ajax.php )

```
if(count(get_included_files()) ==1) exit("Direct access not permitted.");
```

Is there a known method, or fix to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "direct access" and how somebody may be allowed to access the file instead.

Comment: I looked at my cms vulnerabilities on the internet and saw that the ajax.php file was operated for inclusion xss, so I try to find a solution to prevent Direct access to this file to avoid this break

Comment: Oh so, stop direct access will not resolve XSS problem. It's no so simple. you must use a CSRF token. Edit your question or validate this one and create a new one.

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying, but... is this file supposed to be accessed through a web request at some point? Like, an AJAX request perhaps? If yes: you're barking up the wrong tree. If no, and this file is only supposed to be used internally via `require_once` (&co): what is it doing in your public webroot then?

Answer (score -1):

A good idea would be to set a constant to allow some files only to include it:

index.php:

```
define('ALLOWED_TO_INCLUDE_AJAX', true);
include('ajax.php');
```

ajax.php:

```
if(!defined('ALLOWED_TO_INCLUDE_AJAX')) exit(); // Silence is golden
```

And since you exit, the .htaccess is not needed for this.